# Prevent to post to another form present when in different element location

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a form to post a comment. The site requires to have an avatar to post. I want to make this process quickly so if the user does not have an avatar I simply add a link with a class, launch a modal and after success then replace that link with the button to post the comment.

The problem is that when triggering the modal from the link using the code below, the model form tries to post on the comment form instead of its photo form (inside the modal), even if they're semantically separated (see html code below).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $('.idea-new-upload-btn').on("click", function() {
    return $('#uploadAvatarModal').modal();
  });
});
```

Looks like for some reason when calling the modal inside the click function, it is considering the scope of the comment form somehow. Any idea why is this happening and how to prevent it?

My HTML code looks like this

```
<body>
  <container>
    <form method="post" action="/comments">
      <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
      <a href="#" class="idea-new-upload-btn">Link</a>
    </form>
  </container>
  <div id="#uploadAvatarModal">
    modal to upload content using dropzone.js
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why do you have `return` before the two statements in your doc ready method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('.idea-new-upload-btn').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#uploadAvatarModal').modal();
  });
```

if this doesn't work, take a look at this post [event-preventdefault-vs-return-false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) it goes on to further explain event propogation, and events bubbling up by using `return false`, `e.preventDefault` and/or `e.stopPropagation`